# My player moves diagonally while moving forward

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I´m programming in Unity with C# and my player moves diagonally while pressing W. I have tried 7 different "movement scripts" and it happens with all of them, so I think the problem might come from the "Camera Script" or the Unity Input Manager, but after tweaking most of its values it still doesn´t work. This is my code, thanks in advance

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Movement")]
    public float moveSpeed = 1.0f; 


    public float groundDrag;

    [Header("GroundCheck")]
    public float playerHeight;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    bool grounded;

    public Transform orientation;

    float horizontalInput;
    float verticalInput;

    Vector3 moveDirection;

    Rigidbody rb;

    private void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("Mi primer debug");

        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.freezeRotation = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        grounded = Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, playerHeight * 0.5f + 0.2f, whatIsGround);
        MyInput();

        if (grounded)
        {
            rb.drag = groundDrag;
        }
        else
        {
            rb.drag = 0;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 5.0f; 

        
        
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            moveSpeed = 2.0f;



        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
    }
    private void MyInput()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        moveDirection = orientation.forward * verticalInput + orientation.right * horizontalInput;

        rb.AddForce(moveDirection.normalized * moveSpeed * 10f, ForceMode.Force);
    }
    


}
```

In case everything it´s alright, this is the camera script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class Firstperson : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float mouseSensitivity = 4f;
    float cameraVerticalRotation = 0f;

    bool lockedCursor = true;

    private void Start()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float inputX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;
        float inputY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;

        cameraVerticalRotation -= inputY;
        cameraVerticalRotation = Mathf.Clamp(cameraVerticalRotation, -90F, 90F);
        transform.localEulerAngles = Vector3.right * cameraVerticalRotation;

        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * inputX);


    }
}
```

Comment: tbh, id say the issue lies on moving orientation.forward + orientation.right